# What's the difference in merge sort? mid = left + (right - left) / 2 and mid = (left + right) / 2

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I came across under code.

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void doSort(T[] arr, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
      int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
      doSort(arr, left, mid);
      doSort(arr, mid + 1, right);
      merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}
```

I think there is no difference between **left + (right - left) / 2** and **mid = (left + right) / 2**

Can anyone explain the difference?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers can overflow if the array gets big enough.

`(left + right) / 2` is problematic as `left + right` overflows. `left + (right - left) / 2` prevents that.

Comment: for somebody who may think *the division avoids the overflow* , remember `left+right` is evaluated first